# android webservice call and parsing data lib

Tags: android, asynchttpclient

I am working on long term project i am using **AsyncHttpClient** of ***com.loopj.android.http*** is it ok? i am not having any issue to use this lib but i found this lib not updated from last 2 years so this lib reliable to use for long term project? if not ok then please suggest another one i also found ***wally*** which lib i should use?

I have added

```
/*FOR CALLING WEBSERVICE USEING ASYNC-HTTP*/
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
 /*ADDED FOR CONVERT JSON STRING TO JAVA OBJ*/
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

i am using

```
 minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
```

please suugest me a good and reliable lib for long term

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should go with either volley and retrofit.both are great libraries

Comment: Instagram is using `AsyncHttpClient` , it's ok

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/is-retrofit-faster-than-volley-the-answer-may-surprise-you-4379bc589d7c

Answer (score 0):

Consider using volley instead
read more about it here https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Answer (score 0):

you should go with either volley and retrofit.both are great libraries
retrofit is slightly faster and reliable than volley but is also great library i personally use volley for my comfort.and for parsing gson is ok

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Retrofit** with **Gson** its faster and easy to implement

**Retrofit** : http://square.github.io/retrofit
**Gson** : https://github.com/google/gson

Here is example link : https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/